# How to terminate android NDK (native activity) application programatically?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have tried to call `ANativeActivity_finish`(state->activity) from code when application request termination. This works, however my application cannot be restarted and it shows the following in LogCat:

```
W/ActivityManager(  238): Duplicate finish request for HistoryRecord
```

Everything seems to work properly when the user hit the back button, however I need to be able to issue the exit command from within my application. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 6):

That's the way. I don't know how you're doing exactly, I guess that you do that call at the end of the code, then return from the android_main.

You have to `ANativeActivity_finish()` and continue with the event loop until `android_app->destroyRequested`. In your event handler, you'll find the appropriate `APP_CMD_STOP` and `APP_CMD_DESTROY`.

Doing it this way, now I have no problems. I used to do it with exit(0), but that was not the right thing.

Comment: Do you have an event loop in android_main which you just break out from, and let android_main run to it's end?